# Digit sum of powers in bases

Tags: code-golf, math, number, base-conversion

You should write a program or function which outputs or returns the sum of the digits in base `b` representation of the first `n` natural power of `a` in ascending order.

Example for `a = 2`, `b = 3`  and `n = 4`

```
The base10 numbers are 2^0, 2^1, 2^2 and 2^3.
Their base3 representations are 1, 2, 11, 22.
The digit sums are 1, 2, 2, 4.
The sorted digit sums are 1, 2, 2, 4 which is the result.
```

### Input

- 3 integers `a > 1`, `b > 1`  and`n > 0`

### Output

- A list of integers

### Examples

Input => Output

```
2 5 10 => 1 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 8 8
3 2 20 => 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 8 9 10 11 11 13 14 14 14 15 17
5 6 1 => 1
6 6 11 => 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
6 8 20 => 1 6 6 8 8 8 13 13 15 20 22 22 22 27 29 34 34 34 36 41
8 2 10 => 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
15 17 18 => 1 15 17 31 31 33 49 49 63 65 81 95 95 95 95 113 127 129
```

This is code-golf so shortest code wins.

Comment: Can I take a,b,n separated by newlines as input to my program?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Any reasonable input format is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 11

```
Smsj^vzdQvw
```

Note that this requires the inputs separated by newlines in the order a,b,n.

[Try it online here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Smsj%5EvzdQvw&input=15%0A17%0A18)

Pyth has built-ins that do each step for us. We `m`ap over each value from `0` to `n-1`, raising `a` to that power. Then we use `j` to convert each of these numbers to base `b`. We `s`um the resulting lists, and the final list of numbers is `S`orted.

The input is read in the order `z`, `Q` then `w`. `z` and `w` have to be `eval`ed in order to be used as numbers.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
q~,f#\fb::+$p
```

I think this can be improved, but lets get this started.

The input is in the following order : `b a n`

Example input:

```
3 2 4
```

Output:

```
[1 2 2 4]
```

**Code expansion**:

```
q~             "Read the input and parse it. Now we have on stack, b a and n"
  ,            "Get an array from 0 to n-1";
   f#          "Get all the powers of a present in the array, i.e. 0 to n-1";
     \         "Swap the array of a^i and bring the base on top";
      fb       "For each number in the array, convert it into its base representation array";
        ::+    "Calculate the sum of each of the sub arrays in the bigger array";
           $p  "Sort and print the sum of digits of base representation of n powers of a";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E%2Cf%23%5Cfb%3A%3A%2B%24p&input=3%202%204)

Comment: The browser version runs out of precision for the "15 17 18" test case.

Comment: @JohnE Did you input in the correct order? i.e. `17 15 18`

Comment: Ah, you're right- does work as expected with that input format. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) 170 <s>175 196 98 100</s>

**Edit** New version, handles bigger numbers using digits array. Score *almost* doubled :-(

Multiplying digit by digit is more difficult, summing the digits is simpler.

```js
F=(a,b,n)=>
  (t=>{
    for(r=t;--n;r[n]=s)
      for(k=1,y=t,z=a;z;z=z/b|0)
        t=[...t.map(v=>(v=c+(k?w*~~y[i++]+v:w*v),s+=d=v%b,c=v/b|0,d),
           w=z%b,s=c=0,i=--k),c]       
  })([1])||r.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

*Less golfed*

```js
F=(a, b, n) =>
{
  var r=[1]; // power 0 in position 0

  for(w=[]; w.push(a%b),a=a/b|0; ); // a in base b

  for(t = [1]; --n; )
  {
    // calc next power, meanwhile compute digits sum
    y=[...t]
    k=1
    w.map(w=>
      (t=[...t.map(v=>(
        v = c + (k?w*~~y[i++]+v:w*v), 
        d = v % b, // current digit
        s += d, // digits sum
        c = (v-d)/b, // carry
        d)
       ,s=c=0,i=--k),c]
      )
    ); 
    r[n] = s // store sum in result array (positions n-1..1)
  }
  return r.sort((a,b)=>a-b) // sort result in numeric order
}
```

**My first attempt** using `doubles`, fails for big numbers.
JS doubles have 52 mantissa bits when for instance 15^14 needs 55 bits.

```js
F=(a,b,n,r=[1])=>(x=>{for(;--n;r[n]=s)for(t=x*=a,s=0;t;t=(t-d)/b)s+=d=t%b})(1)
||r.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

*Less golfed*

```js
F=(a, b, n) =>
{
  var r=[1]; // power 0 in position 0
  for(x = 1; --n; )
  {
    x *= a; // calc next power starting at 1
    for(t = x, s = 0; t; t = (t-d) / b) // loop to find digits
    {
      d = t % b;
      s += d;
    }
    r[n] = s // store sum in result array (positions n-1..1)
  }
  return r.sort((a,b)=>a-b) // sort result in numeric order
}
```

**Test** In Firefox/FireBug console

```js
;[[2,5,10],[3,2,20],[5,6,1],[6,6,11],[6,8,20],[8,2,10],[15,17,18]]
.forEach(t=>console.log(...t,F(...t)))
```

> 2 5 10 [1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8]
> 3 2 20 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 17]
> 5 6 1 [1]
> 6 6 11 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> 6 8 20 [1, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 13, 13, 15, 20, 22, 22, 22, 27, 29, 34, 34, 34, 36, 41]
> 8 2 10 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> 15 17 18 [1, 15, 17, 31, 31, 33, 49, 49, 63, 65, 81, 95, 95, 95, 95, 113, 127, 129]

Comment: Your last test case seems to be wrong...

Comment: I don't know JS, but probably can't handle big (15^17) integers.

Comment: @randomra maybe, but 15^17 is not so big

Comment: right, 15^17 is so big indeed, 63 bits. With `double` the limit is 52 (near 15^13)

Answer (score 3):

## A purely mathematical equation on the Cartesian Plane, written in LaTeX: Unknown size, incomplete

Demonstrated here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/svpkyarzxh

`a`, `b`, and `n` are adjustable inputs.

To avoid spaghetti code, it's split into two functions, although it could be condensed.

```
f\left(x\right)=\floor \left(x-\left(b-1\right)\sum _{i=1}^{\log _bx}\floor \left(xb^{-i}\right)\right)
y=f\left(a^{\floor \left(x\right)}\right)\left\{0<x\le n\right\}
```

I'm not sure how to put the values in an adjustable list or sort the list without using an actual programming language. However, the fact that this equation allows you to put it on a programmable graphing calculator and figure out the rest from there. I know it can be done in TI-BASIC, but I'm too busy to put an example here.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
Sort[Tr/@IntegerDigits[#^Range@#3/#,#2]]&
```

Very straightforward and apart from the slight abuse of `Tr` very readable. This is an unnamed function which is called with the three parameters in order.

Example outputs:

```
f=Sort[Tr/@IntegerDigits[#^Range@#3/#,#2]]&
f[2, 5, 10]
(* {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8} *)
f[3, 2, 20]
(* {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 17} *)
f[5, 6, 1]
(* {1} *)
f[6, 6, 11]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
f[6, 8, 20]
(* {1, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 13, 13, 15, 20, 22, 22, 22, 27, 29, 34, 34, 34, 36, 41} *)
f[8, 2, 10]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
f[15, 17, 18]
(* {1, 15, 17, 31, 31, 33, 49, 49, 63, 65, 81, 95, 95, 95, 95, 113, 127, 129} *)
```

Two bytes saved thanks to alephalpha.

Comment: Martin can you post some example output? I trust Mathematica more than OP

Comment: `Sort[Tr/@IntegerDigits[#^Range@#3/#,#2]]&`

Comment: @alephalpha Ah, neat :)

Comment: @edc65 Added all the example outputs.

Answer (score 1):

### J - 19

```
/:~+/"1#.inv`(^i.)/
```

Takes numbers in that order: b a c

Usage example (x stands for extended precision):

```
   /:~+/"1#.inv`(^i.)/ 5 2 10
1 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 8 8
   /:~+/"1#.inv`(^i.)/ 17 15x 18
1 15 17 31 31 33 49 49 63 65 81 95 95 95 95 113 127 129
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>29</s> 24 bytes

```apl
{(⊂∘⍋⌷⊢)+⌿⍵(⊥⍣¯1)∊*∘⍳/⍺}
```

-5 bytes from Jo King.

Takes inputs as `a n` function `b`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXECWWxCQZWhkYf6/WuNRV9OjjhmPersf9Wx/1LVIU/tRz/5HvVuB4ksf9S4@tN5Q81FHlxZYyWb9R727av@nATU/6u171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qbCDQ2OMgZSIZ4eAb/N1IwNFBIUzBV4DJWMAKxjLhMFQyBtBkA)

```apl
{(⊂∘⍋⌷⊢)+⌿(⊃⌽⍵)(⊥⍣¯1)(⊃⍵)*⍳⍺}
```

Takes inputs as `n` function `a b`

Thanks to [Jo King](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55516302#55516302) for helping me fix this answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXECWWxCQZWhkYf6/WuNRV9OjjhmPersf9Wx/1LVIU/tRz36gYPOjnr2PerdqAplLH/UuPrTeUBMsChTSetS7@VHvrtr/aUBTHvX2gYXXPOrdcmi98aO2iUDzg4OcgWSIh2fwf0MDhTQFIwVTBS4jEMtYwYjLEEibKpgBAA)

### Explanation

```apl
{(⊂∘⍋⌷⊢)+⌿(⊃⌽⍵)(⊥⍣¯1)(⊃⍵)*⍳⍺} ⍺ → n, ⍵ → [a,b]
                          ⍳⍺  range (1..n) 
                     (⊃⍵)*    a to the power of the range
          (⊃⌽⍵)               take b from reverse of ⍵
               (⊥⍣¯1)         inverse encode(decode) using b till it reaches zero
        +⌿                    reduce with addition along non-leading axis
                              i.e: sum the columns
 (⊂∘⍋⌷⊢)                      tacit fn:
    ⍋                         Get indices for ascending order
     ⌷                        Get elements at those indices
      ⊢                       From the right arg
  ⊂                           Enclose it
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 79 bytes

```
import Data.Digits
import Data.List
f a b n=sort$map(sum.digits b.(a^))[0..n-1]
```

Usage: `f 6 8 20`, output: `[1,6,6,8,8,8,13,13,15,20,22,22,22,27,29,34,34,34,36,41]`

This is a typical Haskell function: straight forward, same as ungolfed version but the `import`s ruin the golf score: for every element e of the list from `0` to `n-1` calculate `a^e`, convert to a list of base `b` digits and `sum` it. `Sort` the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ḷ*@b⁵§Ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4bi2KkBi4oG1wqfhuaL///8xOP8xNf8xNw)

Takes input as 3 command line arguments, \$n\$, \$a\$ then \$b\$.

### How it works

```
Ḷ*@b⁵§Ṣ - Main link. n on the left, a on the right and b as the 3rd argument
Ḷ       - Range [0, 1, ..., n-1]
 *@     - Take a to the power of each [1, a, ..., a^(n-1)]
    ⁵   - Yield b
   b    - Convert each power to base b
     §  - Take the digit sums of each
      Ṣ - Sort the digit sums
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
OmoΣB²`z^R¹⁴ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr//9PbW/Oo0LCsmB6XlLCueKBtMWA////M/8y/zIw)

### Explanation

```
OmoΣB²`z^R¹⁴ŀ
            ŀ range from 0..n-1
         R¹⁴  a replicated n times
      `z^     zip both with power
 moΣB²        convert each power to base n, and sum digits
O             Sort in ascending order
```